# Editing canonical links without a module, contained in $head?

Tags: uri

I've not been using Drupal for long (< 3 weeks) but have good knowledge of standard PHP, so I really don't know the 'Drupal' way of doing things yet.

What I'm trying to do is edit the canonical tag for a mobile site. The current path is realtive, however I need it to be absolute, and link to the desktop version of the site.

As far as I can tell the current implementation is not using any module to insert the canonical tag.

By looking at the source code of the rendered page the code appears to be contained in the `$head` variable which is in `html.tpl.php` as below

```
<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
<?php print $head; ?>
<title><?php print $variables['field_meta_title']; ?></title>
```

I've come across a couple of pages [like this one](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/588/remove-certain-meta-tags-in-drupal-7) that mention things like template_process_html, drupal_get_html_head() and hook_html_head_alter() as relevant functions, but in that example the request is to remove the canonical tags, not to edit them.

I wouldn't mind using a module (providing it would allow me to change the link from `www.mysite.com...` to `m.mysite.com...`) but I would need to remove the current canonical tags which comes back to my orignial issue of not being able to find where it is.

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module.

After you activate it, go to **/admin/config/search/metatags/config/global** and, under advanced, you can change the default canonical link.

Look at the path patterns used for PathAuto and prefix them with the desired base url.

Comment: I did come across that module, which looks useful, but adding that would then give me 2 canonical links as I'd still be left with the one I can't find, which I presume is a bad idea.

Comment: Drupal does not by itself provide a canonical link. What theme are you using?

Comment: The theme is a custom one. It may or may not have been based on another, I don't know as I've only just started working this site. Could this have been added by the theme then?

Comment: It could have been added by any module calling [drupal_add_html_head](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7)  or theme calling [hook_html_head_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7). I would suggest you search your code base for the word "contextual" and see where this is coming from.